# Can I apply regular derivative instead of implicit describing rectangle diagonal?

Tags: derivatives, implicit-differentiation, chain-rule

> The sides of this rectangle increase in such a way that dz/dt=1 and
>   dx/dt=3dy/dt. At the instant when x=4 and y=3, what is the value of
>   dx/dt?

[Rectangle with diagonal z](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l4Fvm.png)

I solve it like this:

$\dfrac{dz}{dy}=(\sqrt{x^2+y^2})'=\dfrac{1}{2\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}2y$

$\dfrac{dz}{dy}=\dfrac{dz}{dt}*\dfrac{dt}{dy}$

$\dfrac{y}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}=1*\dfrac{dt}{dy}$, so $\dfrac{dy}{dt}=\dfrac{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}{y}$

Given that $\dfrac{dx}{dt}=3\dfrac{dy}{dt}$, conclude $\dfrac{dx}{dt}=3\dfrac{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}{y}$

Substituting $x=4, y=3$ the answer is 5.

The answer in textbook uses implicit derivative:

$z^2=x^2+y^2$, which implies $2z\dfrac{dz}{dt}=2x\dfrac{dx}{dt}+2y\dfrac{dy}{dt}=\dfrac{dx}{dt}(2x+\dfrac{2}{3}y)$

Substituting values for x,y and $\dfrac{dz}{dt}=1$ we get that answer is 1.

Where did I get wrong? My suspicions are:

- Maybe it's incorrect to use $\dfrac{dz}{dy}$ when z depends on x too
- Working with z instead of $z^2$ is prohibited

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your answer is that your first derivative only takes the derivative with respect to $y$.  $x$ is essentially ignored.  $\frac{dz}{dy}$ is not the same as $\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}$.

I would, indeed, start with $z^2 = x^2 + y^2$ because it is just a much simpler problem.  Starting the way you did isn't problematic, it just becomes a much harder equation.

$$ 
z = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2} \\
d(z) = d\left(\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}\right) \\
dz = \frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}} d(x^2 + y^2) \\
dz = \frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}} (2xdx + 2ydy)\\
dz = \frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}}dx + \frac{y}{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}}dy \\
 $$
We can divide both sides by $dt$ to get

$$
\frac{dz}{dt} = \frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}}\frac{dx}{dt} + \frac{y}{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}}\frac{dy}{dt} \\
$$
Then, putting in our substitutions, we get
$$
1 = \frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}}\frac{dx}{dt} + \frac{1}{3}\frac{y}{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}}\frac{dx}{dt} \\
1 = \frac{x + \frac{1}{3}y}{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}}\frac{dx}{dt} \\
\frac{dx}{dt} = \frac{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}}{x + \frac{1}{3}y} \\
\frac{dx}{dt} = \frac{\sqrt{4^2 + 3^2}}{4 + \frac{1}{3}3} \\
\frac{dx}{dt} = \frac{5}{5} = 1
$$

Also note that you *could* have used $\frac{dz}{dy}$ just fine as well, but you MUST apply the derivative with respect to $y$ as well for that to work.  So, your first step would result in:

$$ 
\frac{dz}{dy} = \frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}} (2x\frac{dx}{dy} + 2y\frac{dy}{dy})\\
$$
And the $\frac{dy}{dy}$ would reduce to $1$, but I wanted to be sure that you saw it.

Comment: Is there a rule which shows that it is OK to treat $\dfrac{dz}{dy}$ like $\dfrac{\partial z}{\partial y}$?

Comment: It's *never* (well, almost never) okay to treat $\frac{dz}{dy}$ like $\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}$.  They are two very different entities.  $\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}$ is the change in $z$ that *only* results from changes in $y$.  Additionally, because partial derivatives have terrible notation, you can't treat partials like fractions either (this is a notation problem, not a problem in theory).

Comment: In this case, though, you are looking at the total derivative, not the partial.  You can tell that, because (a) the problem uses total differentials, and (b) it asks for the value of multiple derivatives.  If we were dealing with partials, *all* of the other differentials would be set to 0.  If you are looking at $\frac{partial z}{\partial y}$ the likely scenario is that you are assuming that every other differential is just zero.  Since, in your case, the other differentials are not zero, you are dealing in total differentials, not partial ones.